# How to use git for multiple developers

Tags: git, version-control

Here is very simple question for experienced Git user.
I've created repository on git hosting and set up mine pc:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@*.sourcerepo.com:*/ *.git
```

Then, after some changes I do:

```
git add .
git commit
git push
```

All these actions are done on first developer pc.

Now the question: How does second developer access and take changes to repo?
First of all he has to clone repo?

Comment: extremely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Comment: Take a look at this freely-available book for Git: http://progit.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you would use clone. You also should be sure to set the sharedrepository config option:

```
git config core.sharedRepository "true"
```

You should also be aware, with multiple commiters that the fetch option would let you preview the changes in the main repository, and how they would apply to you:

```
git fetch
git diff origin
```

or you may want to simply see a list of files and diff each one seperately:

```
git diff --name-status origin
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's going to be

```
 git clone $giturl
 git add .
 git commit
 git push
```

for him.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of option when multiple developers are applying patches:
With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "`git apply`" adjusted the permission bits of working-tree files and directories according `core.sharedRepository` setting by mistake and
for a long time, which has been corrected.

> ### [`apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb3c027e1779d0d1b5bd3b4e96a108461c9759a5): don't use core.sharedRepository to create working tree files
>
> `core.sharedRepository` defines which permissions Git should set when creating files in $GIT_DIR, so that the repository may be shared with other users.
>
> But (in its current form) the setting shouldn't affect how files are created in the working tree.
>
> This is not respected by `apply` and `am` (which uses `apply`), when creating leading directories:
>
> ```sh
> $ cat d.patch
>  diff --git a/d/f b/d/f
>  new file mode 100644
>  index 0000000..e69de29
> ```

Apply without the setting:

> ```sh
> $ umask 0077
> $ git apply d.patch
> $ ls -ld d
>  drwx------
> ```
>
> Apply with the setting:
>
> ```sh
> $ umask 0077
> $ git -c core.sharedRepository=0770 apply d.patch
> $ ls -ld d
>  drwxrws---
> ```
>
> Only the leading directories are affected.
> That's because they are created with `safe_create_leading_directories()`, which calls `adjust_shared_perm()` to set the directories' permissions based on
> `core.sharedRepository`.
>
> To fix that, let's introduce a variant of this function that ignores the setting, and use it in `apply`.
> Also add a regression test and a note in the function documentation about the use
> of each variant according to the destination (working tree or git dir).