# Is there a reason why "refs/heads/branchname" on the bare remote repository is not created with umask 022?

Tags: git, repository, file-permissions

I have noticed that when I push a branch to the origin repo `refs/heads/branchname` is created with permissions `600`. This prevents a local redmine client from seeing that branch when it updates the repository view.

After I run chmod -R 755 on the repository's directory the branch becomes visible to the redmine client.

Is there some setting in `git` or the OS configuration that could be causing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git for multiple developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492398/how-to-use-git-for-multiple-developers)

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresharedRepository.

Comment: Set `git config core.sharedRepository 0644`

Comment: You can override the system-provided umask with `core.sharedRepository`. The system-provided umask is probably 077 on your server system (you did not mention which OS this is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by gitolite. The default umask in [.gitolite.rc](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc.html) is `077` and needs to be changed to allow the a value which allows the Unix `other` users to read the directories and files.